# Orientating Figures to look at the Camera with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

In my opengl app, i want to orientate figures to look at the camera, to make this, i define for all the objects 2 vectors, front and up.

Im using gluLookAt to control the camera, so the vectors newFront and newUp i need are easily known.

The code i use to control the orientation for each figure is :

```
m4D orientate(v3D newFront, v3D newUp)
{
    double angle = angle_between(front, newFront);
    v3D cross = normalize(cross_product(front, newFront));

    m4D matrix = rotate_from_axis(angle, cross);

    up = normalize(up * matrix);

    angle = angle_between(up, newUp);
    cross = normalize(cross_product(up, newUp));

    return(rotate_from_axis(angle, cross) * matrix);
}
```

This code works well when the matrix stack has only this matrix, but if i push a previous matrix rotation (rotating of course front and up vectors) it fails.

What's my fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why always those complicated "I solve for an inverse rotation and multiply that onto the modelview" billboard/impostor solutions, when there's a much simpler method?

Let M be the modelview matrix from which a billboard matrix is to be determined. The matrix is a 4×4 real valued type. The upper left 3×3 defines rotation and scaling. For a billboard this part is to be identity.

So by replacing the upper left part of the current modelview matrix with identity, and keeping the rest as is i.e.

```
 1  0  0 tx
 0  1  0 ty
 0  0  1 tz
wx wy wz ww
```

and using that matrix for further transformations you get exactly the desired effect. If there was a scaling applied, replace the upper left identity with a scaling matrix.

Comment: Thank you so much datenwolf, i suspect that the reason for the complicated solutions is associated with the graphical engine designed. Implement your solution force me to control matrix transformations completelly (not partially like now).

Comment: It Works!!, only one more cuestión (i dont know if i need to open new question), ¿is my code ok for general orientation choosing arbitrary front and up vectors?

Comment: @ergocortex: Even that can be written simpler. The 2nd row of the matrix is what's sometimes called the "Up" and the 3rd column the "Front" vector. The 1st column should be set to the cross product between them. It's most easy to understand if you visualize the first 3 columns of a homogenous transformation matrix as the base vectors of a coordinate system, and the 4th column as the point of origin.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation @datenwolf. Very very instructive.