# How can I make polygons look at the camera (OpenGL)?

Tags: android, kotlin, opengl-es

I am developing an Android app with opengl (GLES20).
I successfully make it render square polygon models
but I cannot make them look at the camera.

I read the post below but I could not catch the point.

[Orientating Figures to look at the Camera with OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12910332/orientating-figures-to-look-at-the-camera-with-opengl)

**view.SampleGLSurfaceViewRenderer.kt**

```
class SampleGLSurfaceViewRenderer() : GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    var vertexShader: Int = -1
    var fragmentShader: Int = -1
    var shaderProgram: Int = -1

    var attributeHandlers: MutableMap<String, Int> = mutableMapOf()
    var uniformHandlers: MutableMap<String, Int> = mutableMapOf()

    var sampleData: SampleGLData = SampleGLData()

    var modelMatrix: FloatArray = FloatArray(16)
    var viewMatrix: FloatArray = FloatArray(16)
    var perspectiveMatrix: FloatArray = FloatArray(16)

    var aspect: Float = 0.0f

    override fun onSurfaceCreated(gl: GL10?, config: EGLConfig?) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)

        initShadersAndProgram()

        initLocationHandlers()
    }

    override fun onSurfaceChanged(gl: GL10?, width: Int, height: Int) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

        aspect = width * 1.0f / height
    }

    override fun onDrawFrame(gl: GL10?) {
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        GLES20.glUseProgram(shaderProgram)

        attributeHandlers["position"]?.also { positionHandle ->
            GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle)

            GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(positionHandle, 3, GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, 12, sampleData.vertexBuffer)

            resetMvpMatrix()
            applyMvpMatrix()

            GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, sampleData.indicesBuffer.capacity(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, sampleData.indicesBuffer)

            resetMvpMatrix()
            Matrix.translateM(modelMatrix, 0, 0.0f, -4.0f, 0.0f)
            applyMvpMatrix()

            GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, sampleData.indicesBuffer.capacity(), GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, sampleData.indicesBuffer)

            GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(positionHandle)
        }
    }

    private fun applyMvpMatrix() {
        uniformHandlers["mvpMatrix"]?.also { mvpMatrixHandler ->
            val mvpMatrix: FloatArray = FloatArray(16)
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, perspectiveMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0)
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, mvpMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0)

            GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandler, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0)
        }
    }

    private fun resetMvpMatrix() {
        Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0)

        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0,
                0.0f, 0.4f, -1.0f,
                0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f)

        Matrix.perspectiveM(perspectiveMatrix, 0,
                120.0f,
                aspect,
                0.1f, 10.0f)
    }

    private fun initLocationHandlers() {
        attributeHandlers.put("position", GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position"))

        uniformHandlers.put("mvpMatrix", GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mvpMatrix"))
    }

    private fun initShadersAndProgram() {
        val vertexShaderSource = """
            attribute vec3 position;
            uniform mat4 mvpMatrix;
            void main(void) {
                gl_Position = mvpMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
            }
        """.trimIndent()

        val fragmentShaderSource = """
            precision mediump float;
            void main(void) {
                gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
            }
        """.trimIndent()

        vertexShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER)
        GLES20.glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource)
        GLES20.glCompileShader(vertexShader)

        fragmentShader = GLES20.glCreateShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)
        GLES20.glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource)
        GLES20.glCompileShader(fragmentShader)

        shaderProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram()
        GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader)
        GLES20.glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader)
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(shaderProgram)
    }
}
```

**data.SampleGLData.kt**

```
class SampleGLData {
    var vertexCoords: Int = 4
    val vertexArray: FloatArray
    val vertexBuffer: FloatBuffer
    val indicesArray: ShortArray
    val indicesBuffer: ShortBuffer

    init {
        vertexArray = floatArrayOf(
                -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,
                -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,
                1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f
        )

        vertexBuffer = createFloatBuffer(vertexArray)

        indicesArray = shortArrayOf(
                0, 1, 2,
                0, 2, 3
        )

        indicesBuffer = createShortBuffer(indicesArray)
    }

    fun createFloatBuffer(array: FloatArray): FloatBuffer {
        return ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(array.size * 4).run {
            order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            asFloatBuffer().apply {
                put(array)
                position(0)
            }
        }
    }

    fun createShortBuffer(array: ShortArray): ShortBuffer {
        return ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(array.size * 2).run {
            order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())
            asShortBuffer().apply {
                put(array)
                position(0)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Currently polygons are rendered in parallel with XY surface.
I want make it rotate to be perpendicular to the line of sight from camera.

---

I draw an picture of what I want to do.
Like "Best" part, I want all polygons to look at the camera.
Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean "perpendicular" or "parallel"?

Comment: Currently polygons are parrarel (with XY surface). But I want make them perpendicular (to the line of sight from camera). Sorry I know my English is not good. Does it make sense?

Comment: So you have to do a rotation by 90°. See the answer. You can use both transformations  `billboard` and `rotateX`, or only on of them (`rotateX` in your case).

Comment: Thank you Rabbid76. I implemented your code into my project and checked the rendered screen. And I realized that I have described my problem inappropriate way. I editted my question. Could you please help me again?

Comment: I recommend to apply the `billboard` matrix only (not `rotateX`). It is still a bit unclear what you want to achieve but maybe you want to apply the `modelMatrix` fist and then the `billboard` matrix.

Answer (score 1):

> Currently polygons are rendered in parallel with XY surface. I want make it rotate to be perpendicular to the line of sight from camera.

You have to add an [billboard](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/intermediate-tutorials/billboards-particles/billboards/) matrix to the model, which has the [inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix) orientation on the view matrix. 
This orientates the model parallel to the viewport:

```
Matrix.invertM(billboard, 0, viewMatrix, 0)
billboard[12] = 0.0f
billboard[13] = 0.0f
billboard[14] = 0.0f
```

If you want to turn it perpendicular to the viewport, then you have to do an additional rotation around the X-axis, by 90 degrees.

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(rotateX, 0)
Matrix.rotateM(rotateX, 0, 90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)
```

Apply this transformations to the model view matrix, like this:

```
private fun applyMvpMatrix() {

    uniformHandlers["mvpMatrix"]?.also { mvpMatrixHandler ->

        val rotateX: FloatArray = FloatArray(16)
        val billboard: FloatArray = FloatArray(16)
        val mvpMatrix: FloatArray = FloatArray(16)

        Matrix.setIdentityM(rotateX, 0)
        Matrix.rotateM(rotateX, 0, 90.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f)

        Matrix.invertM(billboard, 0, viewMatrix, 0)
        billboard[12] = 0.0f
        billboard[13] = 0.0f
        billboard[14] = 0.0f

        Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, perspectiveMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0)
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, mvpMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0)
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, mvpMatrix, 0, rotateX, 0)
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, mvpMatrix, 0, billboard, 0)

        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandler, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0)
    }
}
```

---

If you want that the model always faces the camera, with a translation, that is defined by the `modelMatrix`, then you have to change in which you apply the `modelMatrix` and the `billboard` matrix. Since the model should be parallel to the viewport, the roatoin by 90 degrees (`rotateX`) is useless in this case:

```
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, perspectiveMatrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0)
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, mvpMatrix, 0, billboard, 0)
Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, mvpMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0)

GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mvpMatrixHandler, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0)
```